What is the relationship between the radiometry quantities and the Poynting vector?
I'm specifically interested in the relationship between the Poynting vector $ \mathbf S = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf E \times \mathbf B$ from classical electromagnetism and the photometric quantity radiance, $L$ with units of power per unit projected area per unit solid angle. $\mathbf S \cdot d \mathbf a $ gives the amount of power flowing through a patch of area element $da$. In radiometry we have the quantity $E$ (irradiance, not to be confused with the magnitude of the electric field) to describe the power per unit area radiating from or to a point. So I assume that $ E = \mathbf S \cdot \hat{\mathbf n} $, where $\hat{\mathbf n}$ is the normal of the area element of the point considered. To describe the variation of radiation with direction (perhaps a source's emission of radiation is stronger in a given direction and dimmer at others) we use the radiometric quantity $L$, (irradiance). The relationship between radiance and irradiance is given by: $$E(u, v) = \int_{\Omega} L(u, v, \theta, \phi) \cos \theta d\Omega. $$
That is, the irradiance $E$ at a given point on the surface is the integral of the irradiance $L$, at every direction.
What is the relationship between $L$ and $\mathbf S$ if any? Can $L$ be obtained from $\mathbf S$? I can't see a immediate connection between the two. Would this imply that classical optics cannot be reduced to classical EM theory?
Any guidance or thoughts are welcome, even books or articles recomendations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux $L=\partial_\Omega\partial_{A\cos\theta}\int_\Sigma\mathbf{S}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}},\mathrm{d}A$

Would you be able to provide more details on the nature of right side of this equation? What does it mean to take the partial derivative with respect to the solid angle? I thought the you could only integrate over a solid angle.

It really means that $\int_\Sigma\mathbf{S}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}},\mathrm{d}A=\Phi_e=\int_A\int_\Omega L(\hat{\mathbf{n}})\cos\theta,\mathrm{d}\Omega,\mathrm{d}A$
